# How can I save SPList in XML?

Tags: list, application-pages, xml

I have some SPLists in my SP.
I take some one List like that `Guid listGuid = Guid.Parse(listID);` and watch id `SPList list = web.Lists[listGuid];`. 
But i don't know how i can save `list` in xml file in folder list?

p.s.: when i say folder list I'm talking about `list.RootFolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String myURL = "<your site URL>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={List GUID}&XMLDATA=TRUE";
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myURL);
myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(0);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

[Source](https://sajiviswam.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/programmatically-accessing-sharepoint-list-xml-data-in-c-code/)

You can chuck this URL into your browser as well and you'll get back your list data in XML. You can include the GUID of a view to filter what comes back:

```
http://<site url>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=<listid>&View=<view guid>&Query=*&XMLDATA=TRUE
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but i have one more question: for what we use View=<view guid> and what we must write there?

Comment: Every view for a list or library has an ID. This is also called a GUID. GUIDs look something like this: `{20BC0752-1B98-4647-A841-2D25780D1EB0}`. To check the GUID of a view go to your list or library settings, scroll down the page and select a view, then look in the address bar. There will be a query string parameter called `View` with a value something like `View=%7B20BC0752-1B98-4647-A841-2D25780D1EB0%7D`. Note the `%7B` and `%7D` at the beginning and end are `{` and `}` respectively. Using `View=<view guid>` in your web service call will return XML only for those items shown in this view